# "The example was not leading" -- definition of "leading" here?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have come across the expression "unfortunately, the example was not leading" in the context where someone asked a question accompanied by an example and someone provided an answer that addresses *the specific example* but not the question in general.

Given this context I understand what "the example was not leading" conveys. It's also easy to see a parallel with e.g. Wikipedia's [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question) of "leading question":

> In common law systems that rely on testimony by witnesses, a leading
>   question or suggestive interrogation is a question that suggests the
>   particular answer or contains the information the examiner is looking
>   to have confirmed.

So by the same token "not a leading example" would mean "an example that does not specifically illustrate the particulars of the problem".

My questions are:

1. Is this a well-known expression, just as "leading question" is?
2. Is the definition I reached above correct? If not, what would a better one be (with references if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

A leading example is one, that allows to correctly build some kind of rule on it. It *leads* to a conclusion.

If you drop a cat several times in front of class and it lands on it's feet every time, this is a leading example for the agility of cats.

Comment: Also, dropping cats is fun.

Answer (score 0):

"the example was not leading" for better understanding we can write that "the example was misleading"

Basically, misleading means

> "the wrong idea or impression".

Comment: No, the example was not *misleading*. It was simply more specific than it needed to be.